# How to make a php/bootstrap/js code so that the admin can upload a photo inside the panel

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to make a online website, it is a project I am working on for our thesis and I tried to research about this code but I cannot find the answer. So in the admin side, the admin suppose to upload a photo so how can the admin upload. Please help thank you

Comment: Give us some code to break our heads on. We are not gonna write it for you from scratch.

Comment: Search for it on this website carefully. You will find it if not here then in tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide code, there is not too much we can do for you. I did, however, do a quick Google search and found [this helpful w3schools post](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) about file uploading within PHP.

When working on the upload page; you also should not forget that if only an admin is allowed to access it, you should make sure people cannot access it without logging in. Of which, [the post of 'formget'](https://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/) can be helpful since he shows in detail how to make the login form and handle sessions

Good-luck on your thesis!